# Segmentation fault error when I try to run this program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "vettore.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc != 5)
        printf("Incorrect parameters number\n");
    else{
        int n = atoi(argv[1]);
        int *a = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
        if(a == NULL)
            printf("Unsufficient memory\n");
        else{
            finput_array(argv[2], a, n);
            bubblesort(a, n);
            foutput_array(argv[4], a, n);
            int *oracle = (int*) calloc(n, sizeof(int));
            finput_array(argv[3], oracle, n);

            if(compare_array(a, oracle, n))
                printf("PASS\n");
            else
                printf("FAIL\n");
        }
    }
}
```

I run the program this way: `./test_ordina_array.exe 12 TC4_input.txt TC4_oracle.txt TC4_output.txt` but it gives me segmentation fault.

"TC4_output.txt" is created by the program while the other two files already exist.

This are the functions used:

```
    void bubblesort(int a[], int n){
int i, j;
  for(i = 0 ; i < n - 1; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0 ; j < n - i - 1; j++)
    {
      if (a[j] > a[j+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
      {
        swap(&a[j], &a[j+1]);
       }
      }
     }
}

void finput_array(char *file_name, int a[], int *n){
    FILE *fd = fopen(file_name, "r");
    if(fd == NULL)
        printf("Errore in apertura del file %s\n", file_name);
    else{
        int i = 0;
        fscanf(fd, "%d", &a[i]);
        while(i<*n && !feof(fd)){
            i++;
            fscanf(fd, "%d", &a[i]);
        }
        fclose(fd);
        if(i<*n)
            *n = i;
    }
}

void foutput_array(char *file_name, int a[], int n){
    int i;
    FILE *fd;

    fd = fopen(file_name, "w");
    if(fd == NULL)
        printf("Errore in apertura del file %s\n", file_name);
    else{
        for(i=0; i<n; i++)  
            fprintf(fd, "%d\n", a[i]);
        fclose(fd);
    }
}

int compare_array(int a[], int b[], int n){
    int i=0;

    while(i<n && a[i] == b[i])
        i++;

    return (i==n) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

They are contained in "vettore.c" and "vettore.h" contains their prototypes.

The program has to order in ascending order the elements contained in the first txt file and write them in the output file.

Comment: The crash probably happens in the parts of the code you *don't* show us. Please use a debugger to catch the crash and locate when and where in your code it happens.

Comment: Please add also `vettore.h`.

Comment: And don't forget to `free()` what you `calloc`ed

Comment: Have you declared the function properly? Because there's a mismatch between the shown declaration of `finput_array` and how you call it.

Comment: Also please read [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: Looks that you never declared `swap(int* lhs, int* rhs)`

Comment: @DDS it's contained in another file

Comment: we need all the (non C-standard) dependancies.... also little sample input and desired output for that input would be a nice to have

Comment: Also a tip: set gcc to output warnings (use -Wall options)

Comment: Didn't you get any compiler warnings or did you just ignore them? 1) Turn your compilers warning level to maximum. 2) Always take warnings seriously, i.e. fix them

Comment: Didn't you get a warning in this line: `finput_array(argv[2], a, n);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem when using finput_array

```
finput_array(argv[2], a, n);
```

Please replace by

```
finput_array(argv[2], a, &n);
```